# Start Sharepoint C#

Tags: development, visual-studio

I'm beginner in Sharepoint 2010. 
I would like to develop a solution with Sharepoint (interaction with api Linkedin or google maps).

I see many samples but **the hierarchy of the vs project is unclear.** 
can you enlighten me on this topic?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a short video regarding [SharePoint Tools Project Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg620644) that may be of help to you. The structure of a SharePoint solution within Visual Studio varies on the type of the SharePoint project being developed (sites, content, web parts, workflow, etc). These are folders, namespaces, library & services references, etc. within the VS solution. There are quite a few 'best practices' that can help you - there are two similar questions that were posted in this forum -

- [Structure of SharePoint Solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3084/structure-of-sharepoint-solution)
- [List of best practices on structuring SharePoint 2010 solutions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11249/list-of-best-practices-on-structuring-sharepoint-2010-solutions)

For a beginning developer, I would also suggest reviewing the content of the [SharePoint 2010 Developer Resource Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/bb964529) including [development videos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee513147.aspx) and plenty of [development code examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512781.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I'm uncertain what you mean by "the hierarchy of the visual studio project is unclear"?  At any rate...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee513147

should get you started on the right track.